# Magento does not display changes committed in the Manage categories

Tags: category

I have been passed a developed magento shop and I wanted to remove from sight some categories from the main menu on the frontpage, yet, it will continue showing up despite having selected Included in Navigation Menu: No

That is, Catalog- Manage Categories- General Information

I also tried changing to: Is Active? No.

and then I click on save category, I refresh the frontpage and it keeps showing. I dont understand. I even checked with other browsers to make sure I wasn't seeing the cache.

I have then tried other thing. At the Directory tree of categories, I have dragged that category up to insert it inside another one. It should have then disappeared from the Main navigation menu and be included in the list of dropdown items. Nothing of the sort happened. It continues showing up in the main menu despite the Directory tree having been changed.

I am flummoxed.

I have noticed one thing and it may be the key:

The categories does not show a Default Category. Instead, whoever made the site, replaced that by a named category such as OurShop.

What to do then?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things I'd suggest checking.

You mentioned browser cache, but have to checked the Magento cache in System > Cache Management?

Is there a 3rd party module controlling the menu? If this is the case maybe the menu is controlled within the module or via static blocks rather than the default category method.